# Scala: Using supertype operator in pattern matching

Tags: scala, design-patterns, types

I have made my own framework of traits and classes that extend my traits. The parent of all classes is a trait named 'Contract'. 'Combinator' and 'ElementaryContract' are two immediate children of Contract.

```
def disintegrateContract[T](element: T): Elem = 
{

    element match
    {
      case com <: Combinator =>  matchCombinator(com)
      case e <:ElementaryContract =>matchElementaryContract(e)
    }
}
```

I want to make a match class that recognizes whether a passed 'Contract' is a subtype of 'Combinator' or 'ElementaryContract' and then pass it to some other functions.
This is the compilation error I get:

```
 '=>' expected but '<:' found
```

Probably it does not recognize the subtype operator. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If understood you correctly the usual pattern matching should be fine -- if Bar extends Foo, **it is Foo** (plus something else):

```
class SuperA
class ImplA extends SuperA

class SuperB
class ImplB extends SuperB

def disintegrateContract[T](element: T) = element match {
   case a: SuperA =>  println("I extend SuperA")
   case b: SuperB =>  println("I extend SuperB")
}

disintegrateContract(new ImplA)
// I extend SuperA
disintegrateContract(new ImplB)
// I extend SuperB
```

To have exact your situation there should be Super which SuperA and SuperB will extend, but it changes nothing.

Comment: So, you are saying I do not need the <: operator?

Comment: @Core_Dumped yes, you don't need it and no, AFAIK, bounds are not supported in pattern matching.